# App not running on port defined in .env file | NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables

Following is my code -

**apps.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/api/users', (_req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: `, PORT);
});
```

**.env** file

```
PORT=8000
```

Now when I run the program though terminal via command - `node app.js`

I am getting -

```
Server running on port:  3000
```

but I want it to run on 8000 and pick it from **.env** file. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

I know while running from terminal I can define `PORT=8000` or `app.set()` but I am looking to pick it from an environment file. Let me know what I am doing wrong here / in terms of understanding.

Comment: But you're not importing your .env file in your app at all. Use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `dotenv` npm package for custom environment variables.

#### Usage

Create a `.env` file in the root of your project:

```
PORT=8000
```

As early as possible in your application, import and configure dotenv:

```js
require('dotenv').config();

// Your .env variables is now available in process.env object

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/api/users', (_req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: `, PORT);
});
```

Read more in the official package: [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)